# How to get glyph unicode representation of Unicode character

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts, uniscribe, glyph-substitution

Windows use uniscribe library to substitute arabic and indi typed characters based on their location. The new glyph is still have the original unicode of the typed character althogh it has its dedicated representation in Unicode
How to get the Unicode of what is actually displayed not what is typed.

Comment: Unicode does not prescribe the glyph for any given character. Effectively, a font is capable of rendering a code point in any way. At the very least, you would need to know the font, then attempt some image matching, though that seems far more complex than necessary. I think you are better off trying to explicitly manage the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of what is happening in Uniscribe is not correct.
Once you have glyphs the original information is gone there is no reliable way to go back to Unicode.

Even without going to Arabic, there is no way to distinguish if the glyph for the fi ligature (for example) comes from 'f' and 'i' (U+0066 U+0069) or from 'fi' (U+FB01). 
(http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm)

Also, some of the resulting glyphs do not have a Unicode value associated with them, so there is no "Unicode of what is actually displayed"

Comment: @Mihai-Nita @Nasser-Hadjloo [See this scree shot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/13783597@N02/5772906715/) in the above image you can see that i typed one character twice so windows convert the right one to different shape to match its location as word initial. Although of that after convert to Unicode i still get one unicode twice although i have 2 different unicodes for these glyphs. Even i can past the new equivalent unicode and i will get the same string. Think with me what mess will happen if i am comparing two strings

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools for this like ICU, Charmap and the rest. I myself recommand http://unicode.codeplex.com, it uses **Unicode Character Database** to represent characters.

Note that unicode is just some information about characters and never spoke about representation. They just suggest to implement a word just like their example. so that to view each code you need `Standard Unicode Font` like **MS Arial Unicode** whichis the largest and the best choise in windows platform.

Most of the characters are implemented in this font but for new characters you need an update for it (if there are such an update) or you can use the font which you know that it implemented your desire characters